# How to compile epublib

Tags: maven, netbeans, epublib

Just want to use epublib in Netbeans.  Author provides no binaries (.jar) and expects everyone to compile.

DL'd maven, but no idea how to use it. Author says to type "mvn package" which is obviously wrong.  Tried NB's to compile epublib as standalone app, but can't get project declared correctly.

Need step-by-step instructions to compile epublib.  Would also like to see actual epublib code in Netbeans.  Also will need javadocs for epublib.

Comment: What is your problem with `mvn package`? This is how you usually build Maven projects. If you want to put it into the local repository, use `mvn install`.

Comment: Don't know what a repository is.  Using (actual command) "mvn package" at CL and I get loads of maven errors.  Assuming maven is used widely, certainly not every utility is named package. No .pom file exists either.  I have epublib source code, but want to compile it it, peruse it with Netbeans and see javadocs in NBs.  maven is the roadblock.

Comment: I found a JAR file [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/eu.freme-project/epublib-core/0.5/source-code) for epublib.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a short explanation how Maven works.

A Maven project contains a `pom.xml` at the root. It defines all dependencies, plugins etc. for the build. If you start `mvn package` in the directory of the `pom.xml`, Maven will build the project according to the information in the  `pom.xml`.

Dependencies and plugins are loaded from (external) repositories. If you have no `settings.xml` in your `.m2` directory in your home directory, Maven uses the standard settings and tries to download every dependency from MavenCentral. If you are either behind a firewall/proxy or if other repositories are required, this will fail.

For further help, you need to add the specific errors from the Maven build.